# Error: Unsupported argument in terraform sku block

Tags: azure, terraform, sku

Im writing a terraform script for an app service plan and I have some issues while performing terraform plan

This is how my app service plan looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "app_plan" {
  name                = var.app_service_plan_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  kind                = var.app_service_plan_so
  reserved            = true
  sku {
    tier = "Basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
```

This actually works.

The issue is when I define my sku like this:

```
sku {
    tier = var.app_service_plan_sku_tier.tier_name
    size = var.app_service_plan_sku_size.plan_size
  }
```

In my variable.tf file, the sku variables are defined as follow

```
variable "app_service_plan_sku_tier" {
  tier_name = "Basic"
}
  variable "app_service_plan_sku_size" {
    plan_size = "B1"
}
```

In this second example, y got this error
[image]

I also tried renaming the variable plan_tier to tier. Same with plan size to size.

Can anyone tell me why is this error happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare an Input Variable value like this:

```
variable "app_service_plan_sku_tier" {
  type = string
  default = "Basic"

}
  variable "app_service_plan_sku_size" {
    type = string
    default = "B1"
}
```

and refer the SKU like this:

```
sku {
    tier = var.app_service_plan_sku_tier
    size = var.app_service_plan_sku_size
  }
```

Reference from https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#declaring-an-input-variable